# 9patch arrow shaped pics

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to ninepatch this image.
[image]

But when I do and use it, the arrow portion is not visible properly. I have different ways bt still not gettng the sharp arrow.

[image]

Comment: Read this guide please. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Add a transparent border (1px) to your picture. Then, on this border, on the upper side add a black (#000000) dot in the middle. And another one on the left side (on the transparent border). That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

and create nine patch like this so that the pointed portion should not stretch[image]

Then you will get images like this

[image]